# gam in mgcv R with big number of covariates

Tags: gam, mgcv

I would like to know if there is another way to write the function:

```
gam(VariableResponse ~ s(CovariateName1) + s(CovariateName2)  + ... + s(CovariateName100),
    family = gaussian(link = identity), data = MyData)
```

in mgcv package without typing 100 covariates' name as above?
Supposing that in MyData I have only VariableResponse in column 1, CovariateName1 in column 2, etc.

Many thank!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the brute force approach to generate a formula by pasting together the covariate names with the strings `'s('` and `')'` and then collapsing the whole things with `' + '`. The convert the resultant string to a formula and pass that to `gam()`. You may need to fix issues with the formula's environment if `gam()` can't find the variable you name as it is going to do some NSE on the formula to identify which terms need smooths estimating and hence need to be replaced by a basis expansion.

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(2) ## simulate some data... 
df <- gamSim(1, n=400, dist = "normal", scale = 2)

> names(df)
 [1] "y"  "x0" "x1" "x2" "x3" "f"  "f0" "f1" "f2" "f3"
```

We'll ignore the last 5 of those columns for the purposes of this example

```
df <- df[1:5]
```

Make the formula

```
fm <- paste('s(', names(df[ -1 ]), ')', sep = "", collapse = ' + ')
fm <- as.formula(paste('y ~', fm))
```

Now fit the model

```
m <- gam(fm, data = df)

> m

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3)

Estimated degrees of freedom:
2.5 2.4 7.7 1.0  total = 14.6 

GCV score: 4.050519
```

You do have to be careful about fitting GAMs this way however; concurvity (the nonlinear counterpart to multicolinearlity in linear models) can cause catastrophically bad estimates of smooth functions.